# Prove that the real projective line cannot be embedded into Euclidean space

Tags: general-topology, projective-space

Can the real projective line $RP^1$ be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n$?

At first, I thought it could because $RP^2$ can be embedded in four-dimensional space, and $RP^1$ seemed like a simpler object to deal with than $RP^2$. But after drawing diagrams and attempting to find an embedding, I'm getting less and less sure that it can be embedded... unrigorously it always seems to require that 'point at infinity' that comes from say the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$, so is there a way that I could prove this one way or the other?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, $\mathbb{R}P^1$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ (namely, any projective line in the projective plane), so since $\mathbb{R}P^2$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^4$, so does $\mathbb{R}P^1$.  But actually, you can do better: $\mathbb{R}P^1$ is just a circle, so it embeds in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Indeed, if you remove a point from a circle, the resulting space is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, so a circle is the 1-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ and hence homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^1$.

Answer (score 10):

In lieu of a thousand words, here's an embedding of the real projective line (the set of lines in the plane through the origin) in the Cartesian plane:

[image: The real projective line embedded in the plane]

Comment: I think this still needs some words (maybe not a thousand). How does this show the embedding? Where is the real projective line?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: I'm not absolutely averse to adding explanation, but as the rotating line sweeps out the set of lines through the origin, its intersection with the indicated circle (marked by a dot) traces the circle. It follows that the circle is an embedded copy of the real projective line.

Comment: I proposed an addition which should make this clear.

Answer (score 5):

$\mathbb{R}P^1$ is just the circle $S^1$ and this cannot be embedded in the reals: an infinite connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (is an interval so) always has a cut-point (a point we can remove to leave a disconnected subset), and the circle remains connected if we remove any point.

Comment: The question was about "embedded into $\mathbb R^n$ for any $n$, your answer is just about $\mathbb R^1$.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann a circle obviously embeds into the plane.